# Почему не работает перевод в шаблонах Django?

Tags: django, python-3.8, перевод, интернационализация, django-template

Проект на Python Django 3.0.
Хочу сделать перевод текста как в коде, так и в шаблоне.

Есть все необходимые предустановки:

1. `USE_I18N = True`
2. `LANGUAGES = [ ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('en', 'English'), ]`
3. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'uk'`
4. `'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.core.context_processors.i18n', ...]`
5. `MIDDLEWARE = ['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', ...]`
6. `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'master', 'administrator']`
7. `LOCALE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps', 'master', 'locale'), os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps', 'administrator', 'locale'), ]`
8. В шаблонах первым стоит тег `{% load i18n %}`
9. Во всех шаблонах есть тег перевода (`{% translate "some text" %}`)
10. `path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),`

После этого всего ввожу команду `django-admin makemessages --locale=uk --extension=html,txt,py`

В файле `django.po` нет никаких строк из шаблонов, а при запуске сервера и входе на страницу с переводом выбивает ошибку:

```
Invalid block tag on line 32: 'translate', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

При чём перевод из кода есть и успешно переводится.

Answer (score 1):

> Проект на Python Django 3.0.

> Во всех шаблонах есть тег перевода ({% translate "some text" %})

Тег **{% translate "some text" %}** только в версии Django 3.1 до этого использовался

Тег **{% trans "some text" %}**

Решений два
или использовать

```
{% trans "some text" %}
```

или обновиться до **Django 3.1** или новее

Тут можно почитать подробнее:
https://djangodoc.ru/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag

Answer (score 0):

У меня по-другому настроен проект, в папке с приложением не храниться папка с шаблонами.

Насколько я понял, `django-admin makemessages` ищет в папке, в которой создаётся файлы шаблонов, а раз её нет, то и нечему заноситься в файл `django.po`